# Customize Outlook 2010 / 2013 navigation pane to add totally new functionality

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, ms-office, customization

I am exploring the possibility of customizing office outlook to add some new functionality.

Here is what I am trying to achieve.

1. Add a new navigation pane functionality similar to, Mail, Calender, Contacts, ...
   I can achieve this [as documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692173%28v=office.14%29.aspx).
2. The main form that accompanies the navigation pane, should be totally customizable. I define the controls, its position, events on the controls, ect. Typical development of a form. 
   (To add on to this, have a similar look and feel, so should be able to use the same controls, fonts, theme, color)
3. I must have the ability to define interfaces, to be able to receive data from another source like maybe a server not related to office server for mails (The data will be displayed on form).
4. Modify the data and send back.

Is this possible?
Does office allow me to customize to the extent, that I can define interfaces and have customized forms?

Comment: Yes.  You've tagged your answer with VSTO.  That's appropriate.  VSTO allows you to design forms (with Windows forms) and design custom panes which will give you the sort of UI features you want.  Then you can design regular C# functionality for whatever interfaces you want to consume.

Comment: Awesome!
Would this be the right place to start? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb386094.aspx.
How about sending and receiving data? I come from desktop background. No web experience, yet.

Comment: It's really a desktop experience.  The only Web-like thing you have to do is consume an API, which should be simple for you.  I think that page is a reasonable place to start, yes.

Comment: @ShaQ.Blogs Did you have any success with this? I am trying to add new functionality with Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013.